# Add pod to the individual custom framework

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, alamofire

**Xcode 11.5, iOS 13.5**

I created simple Xcode project and then initialized with CocoaPods, so the initial steps was:

- Created new project (TestCocoa) with UI and Unit Tests targets
- cd to root dir and `pod init`
- Opened new created `TestCocoa.xcworkspace`

After that I created new Framework(BestAPI) and added to the original workspace as the second project (alongside the original TestCocoa project). So now my `TestCocoa.xcworkspace` have 2 projects. in Podfile I added `Alamofire` only for BestAPI project and import that in swift file. But when I try to build  the project, I get this error:

```
Cannot load underlying module for 'Alamofire'
```

I tried clean up the project, `pod deintegrate` and etc., nothing works. I tried add use_frameworks!, but on that case I can build the project, but when run it, I get another error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
```

This is my Podfile:

```
use_modular_headers!
workspace 'TestCocoa.xcworkspace'

testCocoa = 'TestCocoa.xcodeproj'
bestAPI = 'BestAPI/BestAPI.xcodeproj'

project testCocoa
project bestAPI

target 'TestCocoa' do
  project testCocoa

  target 'TestCocoaTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'TestCocoaUITests' do
    # Pods for testing
  end
end

target 'BestAPI' do
  project bestAPI

  pod 'Alamofire'

  target 'BestAPITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end
```

Some screenshots:

[image: Projects structure]
[image: TestCocoa Embeded content]
[image: BestAPI Embeded content]

Comment: Where are you trying to import Alamofire? As you have it now, it's only linked to your BestAPI project, so attempting to import it from the main app won't work.

Comment: so, should I import Alamofire to BestAPI and main app target?

Comment: I would suggest hiding Alamofire in your BestAPI target, or reexposing Alamofire's APIs using `@_exported import Alamofire` in BestAPI. But directly adding Alamofire to the main app target would work too, as long as you enable dynamic linking in CocoaPods.